# Linker error when building project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

When I try to build my project in Visual Studio 2010, I get the following errors:

```
1>WaveEditDoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int CWaveEditView::selectionEnd" (?selectionEnd@CWaveEditView@@2HA)
1>WaveEditView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int CWaveEditView::selectionEnd" (?selectionEnd@CWaveEditView@@2HA) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall CWaveEditView::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GCWaveEditView@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>WaveEditDoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int CWaveEditView::selectionStart" (?selectionStart@CWaveEditView@@2HA)
1>WaveEditView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int CWaveEditView::selectionStart" (?selectionStart@CWaveEditView@@2HA) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall CWaveEditView::~CWaveEditView(void)" (??1CWaveEditView@@UAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\aottinge\Documents\CS390CPP\WaveEdit\Debug\WaveEdit.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

`selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are defined in CWaveEditView, and I'm trying to access them in a function in the class WaveEditDoc.  I'm getting no compiler errors, so I know I'm referencing everything correctly.  Here's the section of code that's apparently causing the issue:

```
void CWaveEditDoc::OnToolsPlay()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    if(CWaveEditView::selectionStart!=CWaveEditView::selectionEnd){
        WaveFile * selection = new WaveFile(wave.numChannels, wave.sampleRate, wave.bitsPerSample);
        int i = CWaveEditView::selectionStart;
        while(i<=CWaveEditView::selectionEnd){
            selection->add_sample(wave.get_sample(i));
        }
        selection->play();
        delete selection;
    }else{
    wave.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are getting no compiler errors only means that the compiler has seen a *declaration* of selectionStart and selectionEnd and that everything type checked

You are getting a linker error because there are no actual **definitions** of those symbols that are visible.

Obvious questions: where are the definitions of selectionStart and selectionEnd - and are you linking the Doc & View object files together such that the linker could match up the external symbol with its definition?

Comment: The variables are declared in CWaveEditView.h, and I do #include it at the top of CWaveEditDoc.cpp.  However, the variables are defined in CWaveEditView.cpp.

Comment: Then I see two potential problems: either they are not defined correctly, or you are not linking the View's .o file with the Doc's .o file
Can you post the relevant part of your View.cpp file?

Comment: `// WaveEditView.cpp : implementation of the CWaveEditView class
//

#include "stdafx.h"
// SHARED_HANDLERS can be defined in an ATL project implementing preview, thumbnail
// and search filter handlers and allows sharing of document code with that project.
#ifndef SHARED_HANDLERS
#include "WaveEdit.h"
#endif

#ifndef WaveEditDoc.h
#include "WaveEditDoc.h"
#endif

#ifndef WaveEditView.h
#include "WaveEditView.h"
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

double globalSelectionStart = 0;
double globalSelectionEnd = 0;
// CWaveEditView`

Comment: `CWaveEditView::CWaveEditView()
{
 // TODO: add construction code here
 mousePressed = false;
 selectionStart = 0;
 selectionEnd = 0;

}`

Comment: Here's your problem. Class statics are not defined in the constructor like that.
What you do is, outside any method or function, you say:

int CWaveEditView::selectionStart = 0;

int CWaveEditView::selectionEnd = 0;

If, OTOH, these things need to change *per instance* but have default values, then setting them up in the constructor would be all right, but then you would not make them class static, and your Doc would need to find a View instance and ask that instance for the correct values (I have horror memories of the MFC ;-)

Comment: Alright, thanks.  Would you happen to know how to find the view instance that is associated with the doc that calls                void CWaveEditDoc::OnToolsWhatEver();  when you click a button on toolbar?  If I could find that out, then I would be able to get those two integers directly associated with a specific view, which is really what I need to make happen.

Comment: I was never really good with the MFC, but this looks easy enough to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysfkkk2h.aspx